# Why `.Reverse().TakeWhile(..)` seems to have an invalid index?

Tags: c#

Please see this code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test {
  public static void Main() {
    var s = "5401";
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    var predicate = (d,i) => {
            var r = i > 0 ? s[i-1] >= s[i] : true;
            Console.Write($"{i}: {s[i]}; ");
            if(i > 0) Console.Write($"{i-1}: {s[i-1]};");
            Console.WriteLine($" result: {r}");
            return r;
            };
    Console.WriteLine(new String(s.TakeWhile(predicate).ToArray()));
    // the case:
    Console.WriteLine(new String(s.Reverse().TakeWhile(predicate).ToArray()));
  }
}
```

It outputs:

```
5401
0: 5;  result: True
1: 4; 0: 5; result: True
2: 0; 1: 4; result: True
3: 1; 2: 0; result: False
540
0: 5;  result: True
1: 4; 0: 5; result: True
2: 0; 1: 4; result: True
3: 1; 2: 0; result: False
104
```

Why a call to `Reverse()` in the second case does not work?

Comment: Your variable 'i' is wrong.  It will start with zero even if array is reverse.  So s[0 -1] doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah, missed that. Thanks!

Comment: (Why, I got minus, I wonder?)

Answer (score 5):

[`Enumerable.Reverse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a new reversed sequence , but you are referring to same string instance (`s`) in both the loops (which is not affected by `Reverse` call) . That's why you don't see any difference.